# Automating java script popups

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

I want to automate one javascript popup

[image: Web Elements]

and this is the html of that element

[image: Html of that element]

if I don't pass anything in the mandatory field and press enter then this popup appears for that field only "Please fill out this field". So I want to perform that if I do not pass anything in that field it appears or not. means if I do not pass and click enter then that message appears

I am using JavaScript and cypress to automate this.
I am not able to find any way to automate this.
Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: What's the exact aim of the test and what did you try already - please be more precise about the problem.

Comment: if i don't pass anything in the mandatory field and press enter then this popup appears for that field "please fill out this field". So I want to perform that if I not pass anything in that filed it appears or not . means if I not pass and click enter then is that message appears

Comment: Please add those details to the question.

Comment: i have added all the points in the question .

Answer (score 2):

The popup is built in to the browser as part of form valiadtion.

You can see an example here [MDN - HTML attribute: required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required#example)

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Normal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required />
    <label>Required</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The way you test it is to `submit` the form with the field in an empty state.

Then the element will have a property `validationMessage` which has the same text as the popup.

```js
cy.get('input[required]').clear()

cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

cy.get('input[required]')
  .its('0.validationMessage')
  .should('not.be.empty')
  .and('eq', 'Please fill in this field.')
```

Then if you fill in the field, the validation message becomes empty.

```js
cy.get('input[required]').type('something')

cy.get('input[required]')
  .its('0.validationMessage')
  .should('be.empty')
```

Note since the popup is handled by the browser, you can't directly select it from the DOM with `cy.get()`.

The browser displays the popup independently from the DOM.